# How to Customize Scorer Function in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I've built my own score function for Scikit-Learn, Python. I utilize "make_scorer" like is explained in Documentation-Users Guide. But It doesn't work.

My Computer remains "busy" and It doesn't return any output.

My code is below. Can anyone help me out? I am stuck for weeks...

Thank you very much!

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

def my_custom_loss_func(real, predictions):
    error = 0
    for i in range(0, len(real)):
        z = (real[i] - M)
        if predictions[i] > M and real[i] > M and (predictions[i] - real[i]) > 0:
            error_i = (abs(real[i] - predictions[i]))**(2*np.exp(z))
        if predictions[i] > M and real[i] > M and (predictions[i] - real[i]) < 0:
            error_i = -(abs((real[i] - predictions[i]))**(2*np.exp(z)))
        if predictions[i] > M and real[i] < M:
            error_i = -(abs(real[i] - predictions[i]))**(2*np.exp(-z))
        if predictions[i] < M and real[i] < M and (predictions[i] - real[i]) > 0:
            error_i = (abs(real[i] - predictions[i]))**(2*np.exp(z))
        if predictions[i] < M and real[i] < M and (predictions[i] - real[i]) < 0:
            error_i = -(abs((real[i] - predictions[i]))**(2*np.exp(z)))
        if predictions[i] < M and real[i] > M:
            error_i = -(abs((real[i] - predictions[i]))**(2*np.exp(-z)))
        error += error_i
    return error


M = 0.5 
loss = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False)
y_true = [[0.52], [0.54], [0.56], [0.48], [0.44], [0.46]]
y_pred = [0.54, 0.52, 0.56, 0.51, 0.42, 0.48]

C_range = np.logspace(-3.0, 3.0, 12, base=2.0)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-3, 3, 12, base=2.0)
epsilon_range = np.logspace(-3, 3, 12, base=2.0)
tuned_parameters = {'kernel':['rbf'], 'C':C_range, 'gamma':gamma_range, 
                    'epsilon':epsilon_range, 'cache_size':[3000]}

svm = SVR()
svm_regression = GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, 
                              scoring=my_custom_loss_func, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
sv_r = svm_regression.fit(y_true, y_pred)
print(svm_regression.score(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: Your code works fine (once I replaced `scoring=my_custom_loss_func` with `scoring=loss`) for me. Can you try with `n_jobs=1`?

Comment: Yes! In my code is "scoring=loss"... I don't know why I wrote this!
I changed it, but doesn't work.
However, I change: "n_jobs=1" and... WORKS!
Thanks*1000. I don't know why, but it does. :)
My editor is Jupyter, may be is something important. Anyway, thank you very much!!

Comment: What's your OS and sklearn version? Because of some reason parallelism (`n_jobs>1`) doesn't work for you

Comment: My Os: Windows 8.1 (x64)
My scikit-learn: 0.16.1 (
My scikit-image (I don't know what it is...): 0.11.2
conda-version: 3.17.0
python version: 3.4.3.final.0       I hope this question can help someone more. Thanks again!

Comment: This has come up before. Odd. See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5115

Comment: Thanks! I go to read that mountain, hahaha. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when using customized score function ( `python 3.6.4`, `scikit-learn 0.19.1`, windows, jupyter notebook). Looks like it is a bug in Scikit-Learning. Please refer the issue which is still open https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2889.

Setting `n_jobs=1` works for customized score function, but `n_jobs=4` fails. My CPU has for 4 cores, when running xgboost, the computation time of `n_jobs=1` equals to `n_jobs=4` for default score function (eg.`scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error'`).